# Kill TCP Connection for X Seconds (mail / postfix)

Tags: networking, email, postfix, load-balancing, linux-networking

I have several IPs that send emails. It goes like this:

```
IP1,IP2,IP3,IP4
IP1 -> sendsmail1,sendmail2,sendmail3
IP2 -> sendmail4,sendmail5,sendmail6,sendmail7,...
IP3 -> sendmail8,sendmail9,sendmail10,...
IP4...
```

I want to make the switch to the next IP after a single mail sent:

```
IP1 -> sendmail1
IP2 -> sendmail2
IP3 -> sendmail3
...
```

I tried to make a script that will continue to grep the last line of log file and search for "sent" and if found to kill the process having port 25 and force it to get through the next IP, but it requires to restart postfix.
Is there any method to kill the connection long enough to switch to next IP?

Comment: Usually you set one DNS entry for all IP addresses and let DNS handle the distribution.

Comment: What's the root problem here.. why do you want to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let iptables handle nat balancing:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.1
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 1  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.2
```

The example is balancing between 2 ips, You can easily expand it for more.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 0  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.1
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 1  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.2
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 2  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.3
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 3  -j SNAT --to x.x.x.4
```